# Cloud Function Firestore trigger for document at any level to set createdAt

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to set `createdAt` and `updatedAt` accordingly any time a document is created or updated at any level in my Firestore database.

It appears [wildcards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#wildcards-parameters) do not support multiple levels, so I end up writing code like this (for `createdAt`):

```js
exports.onDocCreate = functions.firestore
  .document("{collection}/{docId}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const { collection, docId } = context.params;
    return db.collection(collection).doc(docId).set(
      {
        createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
  });

exports.onSub1DocCreate = functions.firestore
  .document("{c0}/{d0}/{c1}/{d1}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const { c0, d0, c1, d1 } = context.params;
    return db.doc(`${c0}/${d0}/${c1}/${d1}`).set(
      {
        createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
  });

exports.onSub2DocCreate = functions.firestore
  .document("{c0}/{d0}/{c1}/{d1}/{c2}/{d2}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const { c0, d0, c1, d1, c2, d2 } = context.params;
    return db.doc(`${c0}/${d0}/${c1}/${d1}/${c2}/${d2}`).set(
      {
        createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
  });
```

This covers 3 levels deep, and I could continue the same pattern to support whatever level I need.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `.document("{c0}/{d0}/{c1}/{d1}")` and `.document("{c0}/{d0}/{c1}/{d1}")` are subcollections, then, wildcards should make it:

Here the [github](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/bac7d7fa1af027a59379877f9a9c5b289faf1bfd/firestore/extend-with-functions/functions/index.js#L136-L144):

```
function multiWildcard() {
  // [START multi_wildcard]
  // Listen for changes in all documents in the 'users' collection and all subcollections
  exports.useMultipleWildcards = functions.firestore
      .document('users/{userId}/{messageCollectionId}/{messageId}')
      .onWrite((change, context) => {
        // If we set `/users/marie/incoming_messages/134` to {body: "Hello"} then
        // context.params.userId == "marie";
        // context.params.messageCollectionId == "incoming_messages";
        // context.params.messageId == "134";
        // ... and ...
        // change.after.data() == {body: "Hello"}
      });
  // [END multi_wildcard]
}
```

In the example:

> Listen for changes in all documents in the 'users' collection and all subcollections